# Can't understand OCaml trie type declaration

Tags: types, ocaml

I am trying to understand how people write trie in OCaml. There is an example I found online:

It defines a map:

```
module CharMap = Map.Make(Char)
```

Then it defines the type of trie:

```
(* count of members of the set that end at this node * mapping from
     next char => children *)
type trie = Node of int * trie CharMap.t
```

Here is my problem: what is `trie CharMap.t`? I assume it is some kind of map but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the answer by rgrinberg: in OCaml, type constructors come after their parameters. So you have `int list`, which is a list of ints. Here you have a type constructor `CharMap.t` that constructs maps whose keys are of type `char`. So `int CharMap.t` would be a map from `char`s to `int`s. The meaning of `trie CharMap.t` is completely analogous, except possibly for the fact that (as rgrinberg points out), this is a recursive use of the type `trie`. It's similar to the definition of a tree, in that the things contained in nodes of the tree are themselves trees. Here, things contained in the trie are themselves tries.

Answer (score 2):

From your snippet, I'm guessing `trie CharMap.t` is a map where keys are characters and the values are of type `trie` which is defined recursively.

Answer (score 1):

trie CharMap.t is a map type from Char to trie data type. 
This uses the parameter type. For example,

type 'param paired_with_int = int * 'param;;

then you can make a specified type as follows:

type specific_pair = float paired_with_int;;